# Arduino USB host + RS232

Tags: usb, android, rs232

I'd like to get a word of advice regarding the subject. Basically there's a COM port based device which I need to connect to an Android tablet via USB. The tablet will be exchanging data packages with the COM device, but a) Arduino may need to do same transformation of the packages b) the tablet should not leverage OTG feature and shouldn't be a master itself.

So, my questions are

1) Which Arduino board is the best fit?
2) Is it an option to use Chinese boards for the sake of cost optimization?
3) Do I need separate RS232 and USB shield or it's ok to leverage built in USB and data pins?

Apology for this quite a noob question but that's exactly who I am for Arduino platform. Appreciate any answers.

Comment: No Arduino implements a USB host. That would require a more or less complete OS to work. And it's not quite clear how are parts of your project connected together.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I believe Arduino Duo must support USB Host mode, at least I saw that in various blogs and forums on the Internet : https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=548469.0 So, can you explain what do you mean, please?

Comment: True. Yet you have accepted an answer suggesting a 32U4, which doesn't have the host mode, so I still fail to understand what you're trying to do. Did you decide to use OTG, or use a Duo to connect your COM device and Android device together? Or is Arduino itself the COM based device you're talking about?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev sorry for being not clear. Given is a) COM device, b) Android tablet. To be solved is how to connect them allowing the tablet to send/receive data to/from the COM device, but keeping the tablet charged (so OTG is not an option as it would make it into master, thus giving it's charge away). Also, some additional transformation may be required to apply to data flowing between the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Which Arduino board is the best fit? 2) Is it an option to use Chinese boards for the sake of cost optimization? 3) Do I need separate RS232 and USB shield or it's ok to leverage built in USB and data pins?

When communicating with Android you need to make sure that there is software available for doing the communication. That's really down to the application more than the operating system, and because of that it can be quite restricted what boards will work and what won't.

Personally I would go for either an ATMega32U4 based board which provides a standard CDC/ACM interface. This also has the advantage that the (often single) UART on the board is *not* used by the USB communication.

Then you need to convert the UART into RS232 using (for example) a MAX232 board.

Comment: yeah I've got full control over Android app and basically marrying it together with a bord won't be a problem.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled now. Cuz ATMega32U4 is used in Arduino Micro and Leonardo which I believed are not able to be host devices. By reading docs I was leaning to Arduino Due, cuz the documentation for USBHost class specifically says the class is compatible with Due model only.

Comment: @Ivan You want the Android device to be the host.

Comment: Not exactly, I'd like it to be slave and a bord act as a host.

Comment: @Ivan Then you've got a long job in front of you. There's no (AFAIK) API for that kind of thing in Android. You can do file transfers, network sharing, etc, but not serial communication.  For that you *need* the Android device to be the host.

Comment: @Ivan Have you considered connecting to Android through Bluetooth instead?

Comment: Hmm, so basically you saying that I won't be able to use UsbDevice, UsbInterface, UsbEndpoint classes from Android SDK in case if the tablet is connected as slave and won't be possible to respond to Arduino bord when that requests a data?

Comment: Unfortunately, Bluetooth is not an option at all.

Comment: @Ivan The only resources you are likely to find are for using Android as the host. It's the normal option, it's the sensible option, and the only other mention I can find of someone wanting to do this mentions modifying the Android installation and compiling your own kernel. So.... no.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for helping. Will try to think something.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, didn't do a deep dive into the subject but seems Android allows to connect USB accessories https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/custom#connecting-over-usb and I found an example (which I'm not sure is functional) - https://github.com/Geotab/android-external-device-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/geotab/AOA/AccessoryControl.java So, will try to play with it.

Comment: Backing to the original question :) Do you think Arduino Due is the best board to experiment with this?

Comment: @Ivan That is with the Android being the master. An accessory is a device.

Comment: And no, I'd go for a Pro Micro or a Leonardo.

Comment: Hmm, that doc says "Due to the low power output of Android devices, AOA requires the accessory to act as a USB host, meaning the connecting accessory must power the bus.".

Comment: @Ivan AOA is a strange beast. It's not normal USB communication. "Host" mode is only from a power perspective in that system - the android device still has to connect to the accessory rather than the accessory connect to the phone. Also there is no AOA support in Arduino

Comment: right I see and seems it's exactly what I need. Basically the main goal is not to exhaust the tablet's battery. If AOA allows do software side of things on tablet but power still supplied externally, I'm okay with that. Will try to play with the boards you mentioned and maybe Arduino Due too. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Damn, just noticed the last phrase "Also there is no AOA support in Arduino" :(

Comment: There's always the possibility that someone somewhere has written an AOA library plugin for the Arduino USB stack, but I doubt it. You may be working in Atmel Studio...

Comment: AOA is supported in Arduino (or was) but it is called ADK. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoADK. The last time anyone was excited about this was 2012. The USB Host Shield Library 2.0 has references to ADK as does the Due USB host library https://github.com/arduino-libraries/USBHost/tree/master/examples/ADKTerminalTest. Whether Arduino ADK still works, I do not know. BLE or WiFi are better options to communicate with an Android device.